# Windows - Git: staging fails ==> Invalid argument

Tags: windows, git, atlassian-sourcetree, staging

I have a file called "adm.php".
I want to transfer this to my repository, but I always get the following error message:

```
git
-c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks add -f --
adm.php
error: open("adm.php"): Invalid argument
error: unable to index file 'adm.php'
fatal: adding files failed


Completed with errors, see above.
```

I'm using **Sourcetree** on **Windows 11**.

Renaming the file would be difficult, otherwise I would have to adapt some files...

Is there a possibility to define exceptions in the Git configuration or other possibilities?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you try and add it manually using the command line? `git add adm.php`?

Comment: Same error =(

`$ git add adm.php
error: open("adm.php"): Invalid argument
error: unable to index file 'adm.php'
fatal: adding files failed`

Comment: This `error: open("adm.php"):` looks like you have a pre-commit hook? What is it doing?

Comment: To be honest, I can't quite understand that myself. I just have a standard Git installation with no extras. I use Windows 11 and manage Git through the program Sourcetree.

The only thing I'm guessing is that it has something to do with the filename. Apparently the filename "adm" is a problem for either Windows or Git, which would be totally stupid...

Comment: Well.... i found the problem.... Windows itself.... It marked the file as a "virus" which makes absolutely no sense and of course doesn't notify me ...

Comment: Strange. Did marking it correctly solve the problem?

Comment: Windows doesn't *"mark"* files as a virus. Whatever is really going on this is not it. You have misdiagnosed the issue.

Comment: Virus may not be the best choice of words, but Windows Defender still quarantines my PHP files even though there is no "dangerous code" in the files: https://imgur.com/a/Yu1swUH Unfortunately everything is in German.... It's a screenshot from Windows Defender. That has quite a few problems with PHP ...

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who should have the problem and don't know what to do next:

Windows Defender and other anti-virus programs may even mistake certain files for a virus. In my case, this wonderful operating system didn't even notify me even though I activated it ...

Sometimes the solution can be so simple ... Create an exception and now everything works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).